# Submitting form with excel file does not generate POST request in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am developing a WordPress plugin. In that plugin, there is a form with file upload HTML input element. Submitting the form with selecting excel files *(.xlsx and xls)* does not create $_POST and $_FILES requests.

```
 <input type='file' id='test_upload_pdf' name='test_upload_pdf' required>
```

**JS Handle**

```
jQuery('#test_upload_pdf').bind('change', function() {
var allowedType = ['image/png', 'image/jpg', 'application/pdf'];
if(this.files[0].size < 1600000)
{
    if(!(jQuery.inArray(this.files[0].type, allowedType) >= 0))
    {
        swal("Error", "The file upload is not valid type. Please try with valid file types.", "error");
        jQuery('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else{
        swal("Success", "The file got uploaded!", "success");
        jQuery('#submit').prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
else{
    swal("Error", "The file is very big in size. Try again with smaller size file.", "error");
    jQuery('#submit').prop("disabled", true);
}
```

});

**PHP Handle**

```
var_dump($_GET,$_POST, $_FILES); //$_GET => object, $_POST and $_FILES -> Empty

if ( validateIsSet( $_POST['file_title'] ) && validateIsSet($_FILES['test_upload_pdf']) ){
 // logic
    }
```

I bind the input element with JavaScript to detect the changes; it does detect the file upload event but the WordPress does not create $_FILES and $_POST variables and not generate $POST. They are empty. All other file types generate POST request.

Comment: Show your Javascript handlers.  And your PHP too.

Comment: Added. Please check!

Comment: I meant, add the JS code that sends the file to the server.

Comment: Actually PHP code sends the file to the server. The problem is, uploading excel file does not generate POST request at all. So, the if block which handles the file upload not getting activated.

Comment: did you set the `enctype` attribute of the form to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: No, PHP does not send the file to the server. PHP runs on the server.  Show how you actually upload the file

Comment: @maximeschoeni I did not set enctype attribute to the form. Does it require to upload excel files? Can you please tell me why?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter this is how I upload to the server $result   = uploadFile( $_FILES );

Comment: @forethought this is still PHP. You state in your question "I bind the input element with JavaScript to detect the changes; it does detect the file upload event..."  I'm looking for this Javascript - Wordpress uses Javascript to send files from the browser to the server.  If the JS you posted in your question is all you have, then you haven't uploaded anything.

Comment: @EatPeanutButter I use JS to just see if the file is added. JavaScript is there for frond end validation. uploadFile( $_FILES ); this uploads the file to upload directory in WordPress. I have all JS code related to file change handling.